# Android Studio Application doesn't start

Tags: android-studio

I switched from Eclipse to Android. After a whole time all works. But:

If I'm click on RUN, the app won't start. I test with a real device. If I'm removing the App from the device and click on run, the app will be installed, but that was all. I have to click on it to open it.

I added a Android Application in my Run/Debug Configurations.

What I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here is my Console-Output:

```
Waiting for device.
Target device: samsung-gt_i9100-000e3cc647f8cf
Uploading file
local path: myApkPath
remote path: remotePath
Installing application
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "remotePath"
```

Comment: Are there any errors showing in the console or logcat?

Comment: I added my Console-Output to my question. I just replace my paths :)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that in your build configuration, under 'General'->'Activity' you have selected `Default Activity`.

If you want to run a non-default Activity, it will have to be marked `exported=true` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: Don't forget to set <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> in your manifest for the defaul activity.

Comment: I had to do this in modern version of Android Studio after creating an empty app then adding a new launcher activity.